# Csv file reading spark 1.6

Tags: apache-spark

My csv file looks

```
123456

Name  age branch

Mahesh 21 ece

Pawan    22 cse

Count-21
```

It has header(123456) and trailer (count-21)

I tried to read it with spark 1.6 created spark context and read

```
Val df = spark.read.option("com.databrics.csv").option("header",false). option("inferSchema",false).load(path)
df.show()
```

And I am able to read data but it is reading only first column

```
123456
Name  
Mahesh 
Pawan   
Count-21
```

And remaining is not reading can I add any extra options.

Expected output when I run df.show()

```
123456

Name  age branch

Mahesh 21 ece

Pawan    22 cse

Count-21
```

Output got :

```
123456

Name  

Mahesh 

Pawan   

Count-21
```

Answer (score 1):

your input file is not a good csv file.  It is not comma delimited, which is the databricks default.  If the file is tab delimited, you can specify that with `.option("delimiter", "\t")`.  The number of fields should also not vary between rows.  Spark cannot tell from the first row, how many fields are in the file.  If the first row can be fixed with the correct number of fields and the delimiter is consistent between the fields, you should then be able to read it.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
Val df = spark.read().format("csv").schema(<define_schema_with_your_struct_fields>).option("header",false).load(path)
```

You may like to define schema like:

```
List<StructField> fldList = new ArrayList<StructField>();
        fldList.add(DataTypes.createStructField("Name", DataTypes.StringType, true));
        fldList.add(DataTypes.createStructField("Age", DataTypes.StringType, true));
        fldList.add(DataTypes.createStructField("Branch", DataTypes.StringType, true));
```